# Team Foundation Server 2012 broken web access - Error TF400893

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

I have installed TFS 2012 Express on my computer but I can't get TFS web access portal to work. If I try to view a page with work items I get error:

```
TF400893: Team Foundation Server services are not available. 
This is most likely caused by a network error. 
Please check your connection and try again.
```

It's weird because other parts of the TFS web portal works (e.g. source) so I don't think it's network error. If I connect to the TFS server from Visual Studio everything is working, so I suppose TFS service is running.

I tried to reinstall TFS, but it didn't help :-(

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Op mentions: Thank you for your suggestion, I don't have TFS installed anymore, so I can't try it, but I'm pretty sure the error occurred in all browsers

Answer (score 3):

Try an other browser. I have used Opera and got the error. Using IE should work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I don't have TFS installed anymore, so I can't try it, but I'm pretty sure the error occurred in all browsers.

Comment: This is the answer! I had the same problem - using Team Foundation Server with Firefox didn't work as excepted (Always had the TF400893 error). However using Internet Explorer immediately solved all problems. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the account from Applicaiton Tier on TFS Administration Console to your current domain and user info. The default value is NT AUTHORITY.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help. Meanwhile I started using a hosted TFS so it doesn't bother a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for any firewalls or other IPS devices between the browser and the application tier for SQL injection attack rules. WIQL being sent from the browser in the AJAX request looks far too much like regular SQL so gets canned by such rules.

As we were experiencing this issue where I work, I decided to take a network packet capture of the browser traffic on a machine experiencing the problem. This yielded a whole bunch of TCP retransmits on the packet containing the plain-text WIQL. Upon presenting this evidence to the company's network team, they located the offending IPS rule which was triggering on these packets, disabled it for packets targeting the TFS Application tier and the problem was solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Jost: it is an attempt at answering; it may be a little short on detail but having encountered overzealous SQL attack filtering on networks before it is a very plausible explanation.

Comment: Can you provide some more details here in your answer about how you found the issue? Your blog post isn't all that long, and since it is your own work, a little reworking for inclusion here would go a long way towards fending off the *self promotion, it's spam!* reactions you may run into. See the section on [self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) in the help-center as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think it is more of a comment - it goes in the direction "I don't know how to fix the problem, but would look in this direction:". It's a valuable and valid hint, but not an anwer. So it should go to a comment - and if the OP looked in that direction, and it fixed the problem, should be converted to an answer.

Comment: @Jost: but future visitors to this post, coming from Google, may or may not have the issue. The diagnostic steps involved to determine if this is the issue would be helpful in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error while adding a comment to a work item which included a SQL Statement to drop some tables.

After changing my language to not include explicit T-SQL "DROP TABLE" syntax, I was able to add the comment. My guess is something trying to prevent SQL injection.